# Problem exporting due to multiple addresses of one location type (e.g. two 'home' addresses)

Tags: webform-civicrm, export, addresses, duplicate-contacts

I have run into a problem where someone created a Webform using Webform_CiviCRM and for some reason added two address field sets to the contact, with the street address in one of them and the city/state/zip in the other. Now the contacts in CiviCRM have two incomplete addresses, both of the type 'Home'. When I try to export them, I'm just getting one of the incomplete addresses.

[This old forum thread seems to be related](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34024.0). It looks like the UI on the main contact page prevents creation of multiple addresses of the same type, but the API must still not enforce?

[image: UI Error message RE: addresses]

Anyone have a suggestion for how to tackle this and get the addresses merged/squashed into a single address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would fix this either partially or wholly with SQL.  The general approach I'd use is:

- Change the `location_type_id` on one of the two addresses for each contact to an unused location type (creating a new location type if need be).
- Export the contacts with both the "Home" and the unused location type.
- Reimport the data with all address fields designated as "Home" addresses.
- Delete the extra addresses with a SQL statement.

The basic query you want is:

```
SELECT MAX(id), contact_id, COUNT(id) FROM civicrm_address WHERE location_type_id = 1 GROUP BY contact_id HAVING COUNT(contact_id) > 1;
```

`MAX(id)` is the id of the second address created; `MIN(id)` would return the first address id.

[Due to this constraint of MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause), you can't just use this SQL query that would meet the requirements of the first bullet point:

```
UPDATE civicrm_address SET location_type_id=4 WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id), contact_id, COUNT(id) FROM civicrm_address WHERE location_type_id = 1 GROUP BY contact_id HAVING COUNT(contact_id) > 1);
```

You can use of the answers on that SE question to work around that (e.g. with a temp table).